# Selecting Apache Tomcat Server Causes Java EE Dropdown Menu Failure, NetBeans 7.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

So here's where I'm at:

I've installed the Apache Tomcat Server successfully.

I've configured the JAVA_HOME path successfully, and created a /common/lib directory (as opposed to plain /lib) to get around an issue with NetBeans recognising recent versions of Tomcat.

If I select GlassFish 4.0 as my server, instead of Tomcat, everything's fine -- but I don't want GlassFish 4.0 as my server, as I'm working through a book on Java WebApps and don't want to run into intractable problems further down the line.

When I select Tomcat as my server, I run into the problem that the dropdown menu to select my "Java EE Version" decides it doesn't want to give me any options at all.

Has anyone experienced this problem before, or can anyone offer a rough guess as to what my problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Update - it's not a problem with the JDK classpath of Tomcat. Tomcat works fine on the .jsp files it came bundled with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem with Tomcat 8. But after downloading Tomcat 7.0.47 I can now choose from Java EE 5 and 6. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this later and if it works I'll 'accept'.

Comment: Took me a while, but I got round to it! Cheers.